# How do I get a list of check-ins a public place page?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I get ID page place through:

```
/search?type=place&q=cafe&center=45.4521,26.4565&distance=300
```

I want to a list of users who check-in this place.

Use id public page (from first requst) i can get hours 
`/{page-id}?fields=hours` and count check-in `/{page-id}?fields=checkins`

But i find not how get list people who checkin this place

Comment: Of course you can’t find that, because it doesn’t exist. To anyone who heard of privacy that should be rather obvious to begin with, when you think about it for a couple of seconds ...

Comment: @CBroe 
But in public page, in desktop facebook, can watch people who check-ins:
[page cafe](https://www.facebook.com/pages/Mcm-Cafe/445230828831949)
and [list check-ins](https://www.facebook.com/search/445230828831949/visitors)

Comment: Publicly available via the UI, and publicly available via API, are two different shoes. Yes, you as a user can surf to a couple of pages and look at their reviews, no one wants to prevent you from that; that's what they are _for_. That doesn't mean that this info should be freely available for _all_ pages on Facebook to $developerOfShadyAppFromWhoKnowsWhere.

Comment: Access to _all_ pages is not needed. Only to the public page, to give out the most popular institutions in the city in this day/week/month. If there is access to the UI, why not give access to the API? Other social networks give. People themselves spread these check-ins into public access.